# Why dialog box is not opening?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to open this dialog box ,but whenever i tap on it, it shows me error.

the error i am getting:-LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

```
 selectImage(parentContext) {
        return showDialog(
            context: parentContext,
            builder: (context) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: SimpleDialog(
                  title: AutoSizeText(
                    "Change profile photo",
                    presetFontSizes: [15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                        child: Text("Photo with Camera"), onPressed: handleTakePhoto),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                        child: Text("Image from Gallery"),
                        onPressed: handleChooseFromGallery),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      child: Text("Cancel"),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you use one dialog inside of another, you need to set an explicit size for the inner dialog. You can use either the [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) or [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) widget to do this. In your case:

```
selectImage(parentContext) {
        return showDialog(
            context: parentContext,
            builder: (context) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                height:300,
                width: 300,
                child: SimpleDialog(
                  title: AutoSizeText(
                    "Change profile photo",
                    presetFontSizes: [15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                        child: Text("Photo with Camera"), onPressed: handleTakePhoto),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                        child: Text("Image from Gallery"),
                        onPressed: handleChooseFromGallery),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      child: Text("Cancel"),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
),
              );
            });
      }
```